# How to install Rabbitvcs on centos7?

Tags: user-interface, tortoisesvn, centos7, rabbitvcs

I'm used to tortoise SVN. But after switching to centos 7 it is very difficult to use it without GUI. Please Help me install RabbitVCS instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had same problem when working with centos7, ended up using thunar instead of nautilus. See [stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/215856/how-to-install-rabbitvcs-on-centos-7-nautlius-3) and [github issue](https://github.com/rabbitvcs/rabbitvcs/issues/107).

Update: 
I have successfully build rabbitVCS following steps from the [github.com](https://github.com/rabbitvcs/rabbitvcs) and then copied the nautilus extension.

Comment: For those coming here in 2019, it's not required to install extension separately. Please find my solution below.

Answer (score 2):

The below instructions worked for me in May 2019. YMMV.

**Install EPEL Release**

```
export http_proxy=http://{proxyhost}:{port}
wget https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
sudo yum install epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
```

**Install Pre-requisites**

```
sudo yum install meld pysvn python-dulwich python-simplejson
```

**Fetch RabbitVCS packages**

```
export ftp_proxy=$http_proxy
wget ftp://ftp.pbone.net/mirror/ftp5.gwdg.de/pub/opensuse/repositories/home:/hmandevteam/CentOS_7/noarch/rabbitvcs-core-0.17.1-3.2.noarch.rpm
wget ftp://ftp.pbone.net/mirror/ftp5.gwdg.de/pub/opensuse/repositories/home:/hmandevteam/CentOS_7/noarch/rabbitvcs-cli-0.17.1-3.2.noarch.rpm
wget ftp://ftp.pbone.net/mirror/ftp5.gwdg.de/pub/opensuse/repositories/home:/hmandevteam/CentOS_7/noarch/python2-rabbitvcs-0.17.1-3.2.noarch.rpm
wget ftp://ftp.pbone.net/mirror/ftp5.gwdg.de/pub/opensuse/repositories/home:/hmandevteam/CentOS_7/noarch/rabbitvcs-nautilus-0.17.1-3.2.noarch.rpm
```

**Install RabbitVCS packages**

```
sudo yum install rabbitvcs-core-0.17.1-3.2.noarch.rpm
sudo yum install rabbitvcs-cli-0.17.1-3.2.noarch.rpm
sudo yum install python2-rabbitvcs-0.17.1-3.2.noarch.rpm
sudo yum install rabbitvcs-nautilus-0.17.1-3.2.noarch.rpm
```

**Reboot**

```
sudo reboot
```

Open File Manager and you can see RabbitVCS Menu

If the above rpm ftp locations become stale, goto http://rpm.pbone.net and search for the following packages with Centos 7 filter -

- `rabbitvcs-core`
- `rabbitvcs-cli`
- `python2-rabbitvcs`
- `rabbitvcs-nautilus`

You may find these packages at other locations too

***NOTE***: You may sometimes require these pre-requisite packages too `pygtk, python-configobj, python-gobject,  python-gtkspell, python-svn`